# Rectangular gradient in Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to do a rectangular gradient border over an image, the edges should be of dark background color and closer to the center it should fade away to transparent. I was thinking about using radial gradient as I can make it transparent in the center.

```
val gradientBrush = Brush.radialGradient(
    colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, MaterialTheme.colors.background)
)
Image(
    painter = ...,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(48.dp))
        .border(
            180.dp,
            gradientBrush ,
            RoundedCornerShape(48.dp)
        )
        .wrapContentHeight()
        .fillMaxWidth()
)
```

But this gives me a gradient in the form of a circle. I guess that with scaling I could make it oval. But I wonder is there any way I can make it rectangular? I was thinking along the lines of placing four gradients around the image, but they would overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear gradient with stops, so middle part of your image will be transparent.

```
val gradientBrush = Brush.linearGradient(
    0f to MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    0.4f to Color.Transparent,
    0.6f to Color.Transparent,
    1f to MaterialTheme.colors.background,
)
```

By default it's horizontal, but you can use `verticalGradient` instead, or specify `start`/`end` parameters for custom direction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the image covered with a linear gradient will have transparent edges in the middle. For example, if the gradient is vertical, the right and left edges in the y-axis center will be transparent. I want all the edges to be covered by background color, which would slowly fade out closer to the center.